# transforming complex wide data to long in R, multiple year columns, corresponding values, UTF-8 issues (Duplicate?)

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, plyr, reshape2

What I have is a wide format, that need to get reshaped and sorted differently. I have 10 columns in total for year, one same year for all rows, different year per column. These I would like to merge into one column that only indicates year. However, the other continious columns are also divided by year. E.g., Budget | Budget (-1 Year) | Budget (-2 Year) etc., for 19 different categories. Then there are ID columns, and categorical.

So I have tried plyr, reshape, and melt alternatives so far. Doesnt really work out.
On top of it there are some UTF-8 issues I think.

Been a long time since I tried working with UTF-8 characters in R-studio, but I didnt remember having the same issues as now. I keep getting "Error unexpected symbol".

However several of the catogiries also have spaces in their names. Such as "Sum eiendeler".
Perhaps "plyr" doesnt like that?

Anyway, those are secondary things.

What I have looks like this:

Regnskapår Regnskapår (-1 år) Regnskapår (-2 år) .. till (-9 år)

Sum eiendeler Sum eiendeler (-1 år) Sum eiendeler (-1 år)
| R    | R (-1 år) |R (-2 år)| E    |E (-1 år)|E (-2 år)|Orgnr | kommune|   Selskapsform |
|:---- |:-------:| -----:|:---- |:----:| -----:|:--- |:---:| ---:|
| 2021 | 2020 | 2019 | 1234| 1252 | 2034| 14023| 302 | AS
| 2021 | 2020  | 2019 | 9204 | 9222 | 9234 | 78088|3101 | AS
| 2021 | 2020  | 2019 | 1134  | 1782 | 2031| 99054| 3001| KF
| 2021 | 2020  | 2019  | 5034 | 4782 | 4031| 08884| 5401 | ASA

What I need is this:

| Year | E | Orgnr | Kommune | Selskapsform |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1234 | 14023 | 3021 | AS |
| 2021 | 1252 | 14023 | 3021 | AS |
| 2021 | 2034 | 14023 | 3021 | AS |
| 2021 | 9204 | 78088 | 3101 | ASA |
| 2021 | 9222 | 78088 | 3101 | ASA |
| 2021 | 9234 | 78088 | 3101 | ASA |
| 2020 | 1034 | 43378 | 5401 | KF |

And I made a subset of the data:

```
dput(head(subset, encoding="UTF-8"))
structure(list(Kommunenr = c(3024, 3003, 3026, 3024, 3005, 3024
), Kommunenavn = c("B�\u0086RUM", "SARPSBORG", "AURSKOG-H�\u0098LAND", 
"B�\u0086RUM", "DRAMMEN", "B�\u0086RUM"), Poststed = c("LYSAKER", 
"SARPSBORG", "AURSKOG", "OSLO", "DRAMMEN", "LYSAKER"), Firmanavn = c("SIBELCO NORDIC AS", 
"BORREGAARD AS", "RENOR AS", "IBKA NORGE AS", "LINDUM AS", "ABB AS"
), Omsetning = c(1120829, 4560381, 165102, 95528, 534988, 4831283
), `Omsetning (-1 år)` = c(970373, 4109890, 164965, 95592, 590392, 
4447881), `Omsetning (-2 år)` = c(1042016, 3833545, 152611, 
134110, 571098, 4913517), `Omsetning (-3 år)` = c(1139725, 3632657, 
156393, 126319, 503298, 8528459), `Omsetning (-4 år)` = c(1101891, 
3494357, 139160, 127351, 501145, 8629261), `Omsetning (-5 år)` = c(1018331, 
3354595, 128425, 328448, 467739, 9062316), `Omsetning (-6 år)` = c(967473, 
3032051, 128607, 480547, 364653, 9281909), `Omsetning (-7 år)` = c(925051, 
3001124, 137716, 587045, 321790, 11213573), `Omsetning (-8 år)` = c(817706, 
3076555, 135565, 620426, 281758, 11363403), `Omsetning (-9 år)` = c(869521, 
3001972, 143661, 506029, 258282, 9596080), `Lønnskostnader` = c(222248, 
801995, 45854, 44275, 134000, 1638857), `Ordinært resultat` = c(75771, 
625441, 4405, -4518, 20387, 210731), `Ordinært resultat (-1 år)` = c(102996, 
382166, 4020, 1735, 47294, 34840), `Ordinært resultat (-2 år)` = c(129144, 
375137, 3896, -4458, 30535, 134473), `Ordinært resultat (-3 år)` = c(89943, 
468869, 5320, 24016, 35222, 304241), `Ordinært resultat (-4 år)` = c(153231, 
509385, 714, -5844, 46260, 298099), `Ordinært resultat (-5 år)` = c(160850, 
512248, -6328, 64602, 28472, 315443), `Ordinært resultat (-6 år)` = c(154387, 
247849, -7225, -7176, 23329, 564357), `Ordinært resultat (-7 år)` = c(102746, 
212834, -4144, -7117, 23103, 649626), `Ordinært resultat (-8 år)` = c(43573, 
143042, -1720, 2221, 42606, 544287), `Ordinært resultat (-9 år)` = c(55495, 
242609, 3700, -2504, 29300, 620666), Goodwill = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1124), `Goodwill (-1 år)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2188), `Goodwill (-2 år)` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 6963), `Goodwill (-3 år)` = c(131834, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
12790), `Goodwill (-4 år)` = c(134854, 0, 0, 360, 0, 26327), 
    `Goodwill (-5 år)` = c(138229, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39247), `Goodwill (-6 år)` = c(141427, 
    0, 0, 20613, 0, 47812), `Goodwill (-7 år)` = c(144031, 0, 
    0, 23027, 497, 0), `Goodwill (-8 år)` = c(146560, 0, 0, 
    25713, 0, 0), `Goodwill (-9 år)` = c(149051, 0, 0, 36596, 
    0, 77302), Orgnr = c(965724737, 895623032, 935906865, 952070533, 
    979618840, 982085160), `Regnskapsår` = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 
    2021, 2021, 2021), `Regnskapsår (-1 år)` = c(2020, 2020, 
    2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), `Regnskapsår (-2 år)` = c(2019, 
    2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), `Regnskapsår (-3 år)` = c(2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), `Regnskapsår (-4 år)` = c(2017, 
    2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), `Regnskapsår (-5 år)` = c(2016, 
    2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), `Regnskapsår (-6 år)` = c(2015, 
    2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), `Regnskapsår (-7 år)` = c(2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014), `Regnskapsår (-8 år)` = c(2013, 
    2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013), `Regnskapsår (-9 år)` = c(2012, 
    2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

fingers crossed! :)

@Axeman

Comment: Can you please share the data in a reproducible format, i.e. post `dput(your_data)` or `dput(head(your_data))`.

Comment: Using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` I cannot reproduce your error about an unexpected symbol.

Comment: Hi, posted a subset of my data so it would fit. To me, a little strange. Still some ÆØÅ are working, while others become diamonds with question marks inside :(. 

Nevertheless, hope this works! 

@Axeman

Comment: Hard to find out why, I neither can just get my own dput into a dataframe without getting that error. 

Anywhay, anyhow you can re-arrange it to long? @Axeman

Comment: Ok its solved. 

Unexpected symbol stuff was due to set.locale 

The rest is also under control now. 

library(plyr)
rbind( ddply(df, . (columns that are identical for 10 years = colnames), 
ddply (df, . (columns that vary but I need merged = colnames),
ddply (df, . (columns that vary but I need merged (-1 år) = column names),
ddply (df, . (columns that vary but I need merged(-2 år) = column names))

Answer (score 0):

The error is fixed:
Sys.getlocale()
gave "C"
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'en_US.UTF-8')
Fixed it.

library(plyr)

```
rbind( ddply(df, . (columns that are identical for 10 years = colnames), 
ddply (df, . (columns that vary but I need merged = colnames), 
ddply (df, . (columns that vary but I need merged (-1 år) = column names), 
ddply (df, . (columns that vary but I need merged(-2 år) = column names))
```